# Calibrating touchscreens with multiple other monitors plugged in, windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I have a display set up for a flight sim with 8 monitors plugged into two 1070s.

Two of these monitors are touch screens, which I need the touch functionality to pilot the sim. The monitors are two [adafruit 7 inch displays](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2397).

The displays are arranged in this order. With displays 7 and 8 being the touch screens:

[image]

However, when I touch either of the monitors, for example in the middle of the physical screen, the cursor is sent to the middle of all the screens. I assume it is sending the middle xy pixel position.

Is there a way to calibrate these monitors?

Previous suggestions to use pen and touch settings in windows 10 no longer work, I cannot change windows 10 to tablet mode unless all monitors are touch screens.

I also cannot even get into pen and touch settings, I used the following work around to get into the settings:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}
```

However, this does not let me do anything as all options to calibrate are greyed out:

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The only solution I could come across was to make one of the touch screens the main monitor, and disable touch functionality on the other monitor.